# How to access any of the TwoPaneView's ScrollViewers

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, code-behind

In a project I have implemented TwoPaneView as following:

```
    <TwoPaneView x:Name="LibraryTwoPaneView">
        <TwoPaneView.Pane1>
            <Grid>
                <-- Grid content -->
            </Grid>
        </TwoPaneView.Pane1>
        <TwoPaneView.Pane2>
                <-- Pane content -->
        </TwoPaneView.Pane2>
    </TwoPaneView>
```

My problem is, navigating to library always resets the ScrollViewer position. I am used to setting the ScrollViewer offset when navigating to elements, but I need access to the ScrollViewer.

Please advise me on how to access Pane1ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem by extending the TwoPaneView class as a control. That way I can use GetTemplateChild method to get the instance of Pane1ScrollViewer and manipulate it.

Altough that solution fits my needs, please provide some other way if you consider it more appropriate.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WacomNotesUwp.Controls
{
    public class MyTwoPaneView : TwoPaneView
    {
        private ScrollViewer _pane1ScrollViewer;

        public MyTwoPaneView()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyTwoPaneView);
        }

        public double Pane1VerticalOffset
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pane1ScrollViewer == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                return _pane1ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_pane1ScrollViewer == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _pane1ScrollViewer.ChangeView(_pane1ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, value, _pane1ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            _pane1ScrollViewer = GetTemplateChild("PART_Pane1ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
        }
    }
}
```